# which is good idea run large SQL select query script in spring boot or We can execute required things from query and write code in Service level

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am able to obtain all required data from SQL Query. is it good practice to execute big select sql query in JPA in In spring boot. or get required fields from select query. write logic in service level.

Comment: If you contain obtain your result entirely from SQL Query and it is fast, always choose SQL Query over logics. Avoid logic writing  if they are unnecessary.
Ultimately the required data is most important, if you get it entirely from query why write extra logic in service level and increase time of exxecution.

Comment: I can able to obtain all required data from SQL Query. Thanks Asgar